# XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module /c/code/lib-multipart-post.xqy not found

Tags: module, xquery, pipeline, marklogic

I am quite new MarkLogic user. I developed pipeline that runs the following module:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace cpf="http://marklogic.com/cpf" at "/MarkLogic/cpf/cpf.xqy";
import module namespace local="http://marklogic.com/ps/lib-multipart-post" at "/c/code/lib-multipart-post.xqy";
import module namespace util = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/utilities" at "/MarkLogic/utilities.xqy";

declare variable $cpf:document-uri as xs:string external;
declare variable $cpf:transition as node() external;

if (cpf:check-transition($cpf:document-uri,$cpf:transition)) then 
  try {
    let $basename := util:basename( $cpf:document-uri )
    let $rosokaResultpath :=util:basepath( $cpf:document-uri ) 
    let $docname := substring-before($basename, '.')
    let $newpath := fn:concat($rosokaResultpath ,'/',$docname,'_rosoka.xml')
    let $RosokaConn := local:multipart-post(
      "http://localhost:8080/RosokaWeb/rosoka", 
      "------------12345xyz", 
      (<data name="file" filename="{$basename}" type="application/xml">      {$cpf:document-uri}</data>,
       <data name="responseType">application/xml</data>))
    return

      xdmp:document-insert(
        $newpath, $RosokaConn[2],
        xdmp:default-permissions(),
        "Rosoka_result"),

    xdmp:log( "Rosoka statistics saved" ),
    cpf:success($cpf:document-uri, $cpf:transition, ())
  } catch ($e) {
    cpf:failure($cpf:document-uri, $cpf:transition, $e, ())
  }
else ()
```

However, I got this error message when this pipeline runs:

```
<error:code>XDMP-MODNOTFOUND</error:code>
<error:name>err:XQST0059</error:name>
<error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version>
<error:message>Module not found</error:message>
<error:format-string>XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module /c/code /lib-multipart-post.xqy not found</error:format-string>
<error:retryable>false</error:retryable>
```

even though I put lib-multipart-post.xqy in modules database with the appropriate URI.

please help

Answer (score 0):

The space after /c/code is suspicious. Do you actually have a space in your path?

Comment: no space there, it is miss typing here. do you know what security role attached with pipeline execution, so i can put it to execute

Comment: fixed already. the problem i have set the uri in the domain. but i still reference to the module with full path. that was the problem. i just put the name of the library only without full uri.

Comment: @rasheednassr, since you figured it out, could you please post your findings as a separate answer and then accept it? That will make it clear that this problem has been solved.